# Windows XP Picture and Fax Viewer duplicate windows

Tags: images, rundll32.exe

On Windows XP, the only way I have found to open 2+ Picture and Fax Viewer windows, is to open one picture in one window, open the print dialog box, then open the subsequent ones. Opening a picture with an already existing Picture and Fax Viewer window, simply replaces this windows picture, with the new one.

So, in order to get the desired functionality, as far as I can tell there are two avenues forward:

1) Alter shimgvw.dll to stop it looking if a window is already open, so that it just opens another (As it does when one window is locked with the print dialog up).

2) Find a way to script asking the user for the first file they want to open, then opening that image, and instructing shimgvw.dll to load the print dialog for that window, then asking about the second file and repeat.

I have attempted to decompile shimgvw.dll, but I am not very good at assembler.

Have also found that this DLL *may* have a COM interface (http://xpdll.nirsoft.net/shimgvw_dll.html), but not sure what I can invoke by that.

There is also a curious syntax of `rundll32.exe %windir%\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen %1,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2"` modified slightly from http://ask-leo.com/comments_003254.php?page=6, but this doesn't seemingly open/do anything despite what I think it looks like it does (Opens %1, then invokes the print dialog from the context of that window)

Comment: Your question looks like it's starting from the middle. So what you want to do is open images and print them, one after the other? Do you need to use the Picture and Fax Viewer, or will something else do?

Comment: I'm missing a description of the problem and what your question is, we aren't much with your thoughts if we don't know what those thoughts are about...

Comment: Sorry, thought the subject outlined the problem. On Windows XP, the only way I have found to open 2+ Picture and Fax Viewer windows, is to open one picture in one window, open the print dialog box, then open the subsequent ones. Opening a picture with an already existant Picture and Fax Viewer window, simply replaces this windows picture, with the new one.